# Shortest paths disallowing each edge

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms

I'd appreciate any pointers or terms that could get me started in the right direction.

We have a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ and lengths $l_{ij}$ for each edge $ij$ that can be assumed positive.  There is a special start node $s$ and end node $t$.

For each edge $ij$, we'd like to compute the length of the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ that does not use edge $ij$.

A simple brute force algorithm is to run a shortest path algorithm for each edge, each time removing a different edge from the original graph.  Is there a more efficient algorithm that takes advantage of the fact that there is a lot of repeated computation happening in this brute force algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem you mention is called "replacement paths".
Here are a few references:

1. *Gotthilf and Lewenstein, Improved algorithms
   for the k simple shortest paths and the
   replacement paths problems. Inf. Proc. Letters,
   109(7):352–355, 2009.* This paper gives the fastest to date exact algorithm for the replacement paths problem, running in time $O(mn+n^2\log\log n)$ time in graphs with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges.
2. *A. Bernstein. A nearly optimal algorithm for approximating
   replacement paths and k shortest simple
   paths in general graphs. In Proc. SODA, pages
   742–755, 2010.* This paper amazingly gives a quasilinear time approximation scheme for the problem.
3. *J. Hershberger, S. Suri, and A. Bhosle. On the
   difficulty of some shortest path problems. In Proc.
   STACS, pages 343–354, 2003.* This paper shows that any *path-comparison* algorithm solving the replacement paths problem exactly must take at least $\Omega(m\sqrt{n})$ time.
4. *V.Vassilevska W., R. Williams. Subcubic Equivalences between Path, Matrix and Triangle Problems. In Proc. FOCS, pages 645-654, 2010.* We show that if you obtain an $O(n^{3-\varepsilon})$ time exact algorithm for replacement paths for any constant $\varepsilon>0$, then this can be converted to an $O(n^{3-\varepsilon'})$ time algorithm for all pairs shortest paths for constant $\varepsilon'>0$. Such a truly subcubic algorithm for all pairs shortest paths is a longstanding open problem.
5. *O. Weimann, R. Yuster. Replacement Paths via Fast Matrix Multiplication. In Proc. FOCS, pages 655-662, 2010.* and *V. Vassilevska W. Faster Replacement Paths. In Proc. SODA, pages 1337-1346, 2011.* These papers show how to use fast matrix multiplication to find replacement paths in graphs with integer edge weights in the interval $\{-M,\ldots, M\}$. The latter paper gives the best known runtime so far, $\tilde{O}(Mn^\omega)$.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to associate to each edge the length of a shortest path between $s$ and $t$, you can begin with computing a shortest path in the whole graph, and associate to each edge *not in the shortest path you just computed* the length of the current shortest path. After that, you have at most $n-1$ edges left for which you do not know the answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I've accepted the other answer, because it gives more of the context I was looking for, but I will probably use this approach for the first pass implementation that I need.